# how to get the value of a single object?

Tags: python, django

I'm doing a presentation of the sample model (`Footer.objects.all()`) and send the result to the template. deduce the template through the cycle for:

```
{% for entrie in copyright_obj%} 
     {{entrie.copyright}} 
{% endfor%}
```

The resulting data are displayed on the screen

but if I do so sample `Footer.objects.all()[0]`, I get a message on the screen error

```
Exception Type: TypeError 
Exception Value: 
'Footer' object is not iterable
```

please tell me how can I print the data in this case?

Comment: You can write `copyright_obj.0.copyright` in your template if you want to access the first element only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement

```
Footer.objects.all()[0]
```

don't have any problem.

The thing is you're using the same template and you're trying to iterate over a single `Footer` objet.